# using savedInstanceState when supporting different layouts for landscape and portrait orientations

Tags: android

I have an android app which uses a single pane view when the screen width is smaller, and a two pane view when screen has enough width.

I recently upgraded to android sdk version 26, and my app crashes in `onSaveInstanceState()` with following stack trace, when I change screen orientation so that app goes from single pane view to two pane view.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet.
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiateChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:2308)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:773)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.markState(FragmentActivity.java:967)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:527)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:509)
at com.my.package.MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MainActivity.java:144)
at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1337)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1300)
at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:4156)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:165)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5578)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

When I analyzed the problem, I found that when switching from one pane layout to two pane layout, the state of the second pane (which is a fragment) is saved in the savedInstanceState and the fragment gets created again in `onCreate()` of single pane view, but doesn't get attached to activity since single pane view doesn't have this fragment. When orientation is changed again to landscape, sdk tries to save the state of this un-attached fragment, and crashes as mentioned above.

To fix this, I saved the orientation of the device in `onSaveInstanceState()` and in `onCreate()`, passed the savedInstanceState to `super.onCreate()` only if the current orientation is the same as the saved orientation.

My question is, whether this is an android bug, or is it not supposed to pass the savedInstanceState of the activity in landscape orientation to `onCreate()` of portrait activity, when the activity uses a different layout?

Comment: How are the fragments added to the activity?

Comment: I have the same crash, but with the different scenario, try to update support library to 27.0.1 https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-0-1